# Is hippopotomonstrosesquippedaliophilia a word?

Tags: antonyms, is-it-a-word

I'd like to know if *hippopotomonstrosesquippedaliophilia*, my proposed opposite of *hippopotomonstrosesquippedaliophobia* is a real word or condition.  I know -*philia* is the opposite of -*phobia* and -*phile* is the opposite of -*phobic*, so I was wondering if there is an opposite to every -*phobia* word.

Comment: If _hippopotomonstrosesquippedaliophobia_ is a real word (which it arguably is), then surely so is its logical _-philia_ counterpart. At least, anyone who can be expected to know the former can also be expected to immediately understand the latter.

Comment: But is there an authoritative opposite to every -phobia word?

Comment: There is no authority that decides what is and isn’t a word in English at all. There’s no authority that says _hippopotomonstrosesquippedaliophobia_ (a recent, humorous, and deliberately unetymological coinage) is a word to begin with, but the fact that so many people know and use it is good evidence that it is. What kind of authority are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's a word?

Is hippopotomonstrosesquippedaliophobi**c** a word?  Is hippopotomonstrosesquippedaliophob**e** a word?  Is **anti**-hippopotomonstrosesquippedaliophobic a word?  Is supercalifragilisticexpialidocious a word?

**There's no official board of English language authorities who make judgements about what is and isn't a word**. If a combination of letters, or a combination of sounds can be understood by people, then it should probably count as a word.

In English, you can produce new words by adding prefixes or suffixes to them. The new word you produce may not represent anything than exists, but that doesn't mean it's not a word.

Hippopotomonstrosesquippedaliophilia is a real word, whether or not it's a real condition.

So, to answer your question, is there an opposite to every -phobia word, yes there is a word that means the opposite, but that word may not describe a real thing.